# Dynamically load iframe on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a **bootstrap 3** columns youtube videos

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="video_img_wrapper">
    <img class="video_img" data-toggle="modal" class="ytVideo" id="'.$item->id->videoId.'" data-target="#myModal_'.$item->id->videoId.'" src="'.$thumbnailUrl.'" />
    <img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/assets/img/playicon-nl.png" class="fa-play-circle-o" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_'.$item->id->videoId.'" />
  </div>
  <div class="video_title"><span>'. $item->snippet->title .'</span></div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade youtube-modal" id="myModal_'.$item->id->videoId.'" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-body" id="videoModalBody"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I am injecting an iframe using jquery in the `#videoModalBody` div

```
$(".video_img").click(function(evt){
  var videoId = $(this).attr("id");
  var iframe = '<iframe enablejsapi=1 id="myModal_'+videoId+'" width="850" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+videoId+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
  $("#videoModalBody").append(iframe);
});
```

How can I change my Javascript so when I click on another video the previous one gets removed out of the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a global `class` on `iframe` then remove all `iframe` before append new one:

```
$('.globalIframe').remove();
$("#videoModalBody").append(iframe);
```

```js
$(".video_img").click(function(evt) {
  var videoId = $(this).attr("id");
  var iframe = '<iframe enablejsapi=1 id="myModal_' + videoId + '" class="globalIframe" width="850" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
  $('.globalIframe').remove();
  $("#videoModalBody").append(iframe);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="video_img">Click Me</a>
<div id="videoModalBody"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference it by class name or store a reference in a variable, IE:

```
var videoId = null; // Shared reference
$(".video_img").click(function(evt){
    if (videoId) $('#'+videoId).remove(); //remove previous videos if present
    videoId = $(this).attr("id"); //store new id
    var iframe = '<iframe enablejsapi=1 id="myModal_'+videoId+'" width="850" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+videoId+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
              $("#videoModalBody").append(iframe);
          });
```